# Error: win is undefined

Tags: c++, input, visual-studio-2013, glfw

So I'm trying to follow a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVDK9THbxmY) but when I get to around 13:00 mins in, I get an error which says

> win is undefined

I know what this means of course, but I didn't find anything in his episode where he defines `win`. I'm really stuck for answers and could use some help!

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        window* win = (window*) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    }
```

Could you please stop down voting my comment? My comment is asking a question that yous clearly think is a type error or something along the lines.

*Edit:Edit: I figured it out. In Solution directory, there were a )/ after configuration, I changed it to )\ and changed visual studio to 64x and it fixed it. Oh, and could you please remove these down votes? Thanks.

Comment: What did you want to do here: ***window* win = (window*);**

Comment: It would take to long to explain^

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's not what the code is doing.  [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06) returns a `void *` defined by the user with `glfwSetWindowUserPointer `. @Unknown you should put in your question everything we need to understand it, without us having to watch a video. You are defining `win` here so it is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Now with the semicolon removed, one problem is window is used as a type and a variable.

Comment: @drescherjm what do you mean?

Comment: Edit: I figured it out. In Solution directory, there were a )/ after configuration, I changed it to )\ and changed visual studio to 64x and it fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Two changes: 
1. Remove the semicolon after (window*)
2. Change window* to Window* with Capital W

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
        Window* win = (Window*) glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);  
}
```

Comment: 1. That's not meant to be there and it doesn't make a difference if don't have it there. I purposely put it there so I didn't have to look at another red line. 
2. Do you really think change the w to a capital will make a difference? Really?

Comment: Those are the errors I could track from your code snippet. Check your declaration, libraries to be included.

Comment: They're all included, mate

Comment: @Unknown. your comment makes no sense. Ganesh's code compiles and yours doesn't,  and C++ is case-sensitive so changing `w` to `W` really does make a difference

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I figured it out. In Solution directory, there were a )/ after configuration, I changed it to )\ and changed visual studio to 64x and it fixed it.